# Fields and Groups equivalent

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Are the following two statements equivalent to each other ?

1) $(R,+,*)$ is a field

2) $(R,+)$ is an abelian group and $(R\setminus\{0_R\},*)$ is an abelian group

If not give an example.

Comment: Are you trying to typeset $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. $(1) \implies (2)$, but one also needs that multiplication distributes across addition to go the other way.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is one more property satisfied in a field: the distributivity between $+$ and $\times$.

If the distributivity is satisfied, then $A$ is a ring in which non zero elements are $\times$-invertible. It is, indeed, a field.